# My strlen code segfaults

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strlen

Can someone tell m why am i getting sigsegv on this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char szInput[256];
  printf ("Enter a sentence: ");
  fgets (szInput, 256, stdin);

  size_t n = (unsigned)strlen(szInput);
  printf ("The sentence entered is %ld characters long.\n", n);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run it segfaults.

```
unix>strlen_ex
Enter a sentence: foo bar burr
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Are you sure the program you run is the same as the code you put in the question? Because there is nothing wrong with the code in your question.

Comment: Btw, the cast is unnecessary, `strlen` already returns `size_t`.

Comment: And you should use `%zu` to print `size_t`, but that shouldn't cause segfault.

Comment: @Nobilis More precisely, the cast is wrong, because `%ld` requires the corresponding argument to be a `long`. `size_t` is to be printed using `%zu`. (And usually, `size_t` is an `unsigned long`, so the cast is most probably *doubly wrong.*)

Comment: It works for me (I used Cygwin `cc`to compile): 
`Enter a sentence: foo bar burr` => `The sentence entered is 13 characters long.`

Be careful though: as `fgets()` adds a NULL termination character to the input, you must read up to 255 chars, not 256.

Comment: @Shlublu And `fgets()` also takes care of the NUL terminator, so passing in 256 as the buffer size is **just fine.** Read the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) of `fgets()`.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Caramba, that's true. I've been making this same mistake for 15 years, I always forget (I've read the doc though!). Please ignore my comment @user2252999.

Comment: This is running fine on VS2010 too.

Comment: @user2252999 If the code is exactly same which gives you segmentation fault then i really want to know what solution you got.Its a request to let us know the solution.

Comment: @devnull im using gcc 4.3.2 in eclipse helios cdt on suse linux with glibc 2.11.3

Comment: And yes it still breaks for me, even with the cast changes that you have suggested :|

Comment: @H2CO3 Or read the [current version](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) of the [documentation of `fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html), which is, yes, word-for-word identical in the relevant sections.

Answer (score 0):

I can see no reason for it to crash as it is, but there is potential...

It is best to pass `sizeof szInput` instead of explicit 256.  This prevents you from accidentally getting the wrong size in the `fgets`.

```
char szInput[256];
printf ("Enter a sentence: ");
fgets (szInput, sizeof szInput, stdin);
```

For example if you set the array to 8 bytes, leave the `fgets` call at 256 and enter "hello world":

```
char szInput[8];
printf ("Enter a sentence: ");
fgets (szInput, 256, stdin);
```

then the fgets call will write beyond the end of `szInput`.  As this is on the stack it will potentially overwrite something important (such as the `fgets` stack frame).  Then it really will segfault (or fail anyway).